# User X not authorized to perform cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource arn:cloudformation:ap-xx-x:transform:Serverless-2016-10-31

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, sam

Beginning with a new stack I get the error message as in the title.
I am using SAM, and I am confused, why it wants to update the macro.
I thought, this macro is provided by aws and I wonder why it is requesting to modify it.

My template spins up a lambda, a database and a REST api, but does even try to touch existing macros.

Answer (score 0):

My template  did contain the `TableName` tag for a DynamoDb.

As I am aware, named tables cannot be updated, if resource replacement required. I was not trying to do updates on that resource though.
The table existed before I cloudformed that new stack though.